# Responsive Windows App Element

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Is there any XAML element that  will automatically wrap to a new line for sub elements that don't have enough room on a line?

What I mean is that on a wide screen I'll get:

```
Box1 Box2 Box3
```

And on a narrow one:

```
Box1 Box2

Box3
```

*Without* having to listen to events and fix it by code.

The comments mention `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as a solution. But I can't figure out how to make it wrap.

Comment: Sounds like [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid.aspx)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599424/what-is-the-wpf-equivilant-for-the-flowlayoutpanel

Comment: @Gusman ya `WrapPanel` isn't in UWP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP WrapPanel Replacement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309439/uwp-wrappanel-replacement) -- which of course found right after commenting.

Comment: Good to know @ChrisW. I did not saw the tags and the question doesn't asks explicitly for UWP, just xaml. Good point.

Comment: @Gusman yea some of the little nuance differences are a pain in the @$$

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks. I'm checking that out now. (Trying to figure out how to get  it to wrap.)

Comment: @ChrisW. OK. I can't seem to make it wrap. What's the secret?

Comment: Not much, set the orientation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple GridView to do it. If you don't set a **Height**, it should work like a charm.

```
<GridView Name="xConcerts" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Artist.UpcomingEvents, Mode=OneWay}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="songkick:EventExt">
            <Border CornerRadius="8" Background="{ThemeResource ThemeGrayHighColorBrush}" Opacity="0.8">
                <StackPanel Margin="18,2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FullDisplayDate, Converter={StaticResource FormatStringToDateDayConverter}}" Style="{ThemeResource ThemeDateBoldStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FullDisplayDate, Converter={StaticResource FormatStringToDateMonthConverter}}" Style="{ThemeResource ThemeDateBoldStyle}" Margin="0,-4,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <RepositionThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, using the **WrapPanel** control in [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) will meet your needs.
*Sample code here*:

```
<Page x:Class="TestDemo.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:Tool="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="using:TestDemo"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">

<Tool:WrapPanel>
    <Button Width="200" Margin="10">1</Button>
    <Button Width="200" Margin="10">2</Button>
    <Button Width="200" Margin="10">3</Button>
</Tool:WrapPanel>
</Page>
```

*And the output here*:[image: output]